# How to prevent query strings persisting on certain page templates

Tags: plugins

When I do a search, WordPress attaches a query string into the url (e.g. `animalwordpresssite.com/?s=bears` )

If I then click a post from that search, the query string persists and stays in the URL. Additionally, all the links within that post's page have been appended with the URL wherever there is an `<a>` attribute.

I'm not sure how or why this instance of WordPress is doing this, is there any way to remove the query string from the links in the page?

I've thought about using JavaScript, but would prefer to do it using a WordPress filter

Comment: This is not default behavior. This is coming from your theme or a plugin.

Comment: Just as @PieterGoosen said, this is from your theme / plugin. And by the looks of it I think this is done for some kind of SEO purposes to see how the users got to that specific page (what search term did they use).

Comment: THanks, any ideas of WordPress hooks that may have been used to implement this?